# Removing hyperlink borders from ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I don't want to disable hyper reference package as I like those borders in the text. I just want to remove borders around chapters/sections in the table of contents if possible. Any idea? E.g.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{AAA}
\section{aaa}
\subsection{aaa}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option `hidelinks` can also be used after `\begin{document}`:

```
\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

By using a group, the previous setting is restored afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, it does work perfectly. And I believe that the obtained knowledge of groups will be of use in the near future as well!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Accidentally clicked on +1 :-). This is not the solution to my problems as it kills the click-ability of ToC. Thank you though.